I have created a 16 bit xy virtual mouse with raw-gadget. However, its too fast. This can't be normal?
So uint16 0-65535 idk the exact middle split on this cause it's a float but I do 32766 and down then 32769 and up.
Dumping the second EP, I can see when I REALLY move the mouse, it still is moving very little. +/- 1.
Thats a whole lot of wasted bits. Now I duped a real device so maybe it's something they did. But it just goes wild when I inject events. Way too fast even with the 32766/32769. I inject events at ~10ms per. So 100 times a second. That doesn't feel out of line? So even if it's minimal movement at 1 it should not be so fast.
The question is simply, do most mice use this bit space effectively or is this normal?
I don't think I'm doing anything wrong. Why can't I hold all these bits?

Mouse input in Win32 can be absolute or relative.
In case of absolute input - it coordinates should be scaled to 0..65535 (USHRT_MAX) range.
In relative input it is expected that you send positive\negative coordinate shift. See MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE in MOUSEINPUT structure and MOUSE_MOVE_ABSOLUTE in RAWMOUSE structure.
From leaked Windows XP source code drivers/input/hidport/mouhid/pnp.c:
if (!NT_SUCCESS (status = HidP_GetSpecificValueCaps(
                                       HidP_Input,
                                       HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC,
                                       0,
                                       HID_USAGE_GENERIC_X,
                                       &valueCaps,
                                       &slength,
                                       preparsedData) ) ) {
        goto MouHid_StartDeviceReject;
    }

    ASSERT (1 == slength);

    if (valueCaps.IsAbsolute) {
....
            //
            // No switches with which to play.  Do what seems natural
            //
            Data->InputData.Flags = MOUSE_MOVE_ABSOLUTE;
            hid->IsAbsolute = TRUE;
        }

    } else {
        Data->InputData.Flags = MOUSE_MOVE_RELATIVE;
        hid->IsAbsolute = FALSE;
    }

    //
    // Determine X axis usage value's bit size.
    //
    hid->BitSize.X = valueCaps.BitSize;
    hid->MaxX = valueCaps.PhysicalMax;
    hid->MaxX = (hid->MaxX) ? (hid->MaxX) : ((1 << (hid->BitSize.X - 1)) - 1);


So HID mouse driver basically checks if HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC/HID_USAGE_GENERIC_X have absolute flag in report descriptor to switch between these modes.
And then scales received value from HID mouse from 0..PhysicalMax to 0..65535 range: (/drivers/input/hidport/mouhid/read.c):
#define MOUHID_RIUT_ABSOLUTE_POINTER_MAX 0xFFFF

if (hid->IsAbsolute) {
    //
    // We need to scale this value from the physical max
    //
    scratch = ((LONGLONG)(Data->InputData.LastX) *
               MOUHID_RIUT_ABSOLUTE_POINTER_MAX) /
               hid->MaxX;
    Data->InputData.LastX = (LONG) scratch;
}

Also, for relative mode Logical Minimum, Logical Maximum, Physical Minimum, Physical Maximum, Unit Exponent, Unit - all should be set properly in report descriptor. See 6.2.2.7 Global Items and E.10 Report Descriptor (Mouse) sections in HID spec.

I inject events at ~10ms per. So 100 times a second. That doesn't feel out of line?

It should be okay - usual poll rate for USB mouse is 8ms/125Hz.
